# "low quality/auto" flag text is blank

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, automatic-flags

[image: Screenshot]

I've noticed that the "low quality/auto" flag text is blank on superuser.com — [this is the specific post](https://superuser.com/questions/162552/how-can-you-select-text-in-a-windows-command-prompt-without-using-the-mouse/1160870#1160870), and it's not happening on other sorts of flags.

I'm running Firefox 50.1.0, 64 bit on Windows 10 version 1607. Tried it in safe mode (with no addons) as well as in normal usage, so it's *unlikely* to be a rogue extension.

As Monica pointed out, it seems to be there after 15 minutes. Never noticed that before. Is this expected behaviour? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I sometimes see that when a VLQ or NAA flag from a user (and I think also from Community) is in its first 15 minutes, when it's held back from moderators for the community to handle first. In that case, I don't see the flag on the flags page at all, but if I go to the question page I see this.